# Изменение позиций

Tags: 1с, битрикс

Сайт на Битриксе, на нем каталог товаров и настроено то, что несколько позиций выходит на главную. Как эти позиции поменять, кто-нибудь в курсе? А то я с этой "СУПЕРАДМИНКОЙ" заморочилась.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без видимости админки, это проблематично.

Скорее всего там в товарах есть галочка выводить на главной. В шаблон главной страницы есть условие вывода по этой самой галочке.

Так что ковырять нужно там. в товарах.

Answer (score 0):

Лучшая помощь будет здесь [Пользовательская документация](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/store/sale/index.php)